# i have 3 tables which have many to many relationship with each other,now how to fetch data using mysql in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

there is students table with id, name, address and there is tests table with id,test_type.students and tests table have many to many relationships .so there is pivot table student_test with student_id,test_id attributes. And there are 3rd table subjects with id,sub_name.tests and subjects also have many to many relationships.So there is a pivot table subject_test with test_id,subject_id attributes. Now I want to get test_type and sub_name of the student.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like a messy, try to rephrase your question by using available format tools and share your tables structure for `students`, `student_test` etc
. Otherwise, no one will spend his/her time guessing how your database schema is organised.